# Add to cart button is not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, jquery

Add to cart button is not working.

Is this due to any jQuery conflict.

I am not using any custom jQuery for add to cart button but had used many extension which had jQuery.

On clicking add to cart button, no action no effect is performed, even nothing is displayed in firebug console.

Can any one tell me how to debug this.

Comment: what about showing us some code?

Comment: html with the button and js function

Comment: I have not added any js code and the button code is the default one that comes with magento

Comment: write jQuery in console and check if its not undefined

Comment: I think it is defined, its show function link in console

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33908/discussion-between-user2293790-and-alex-kneller)

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted switching on the default template for Magento to see if it could be something in your custom theme? Have you attempted in another browser?

I have most commonly seen the "add to cart" button cease if there were a jQuery conflict or if the button class/name had been changed.

Not sure if you're on version control but if you have migrated the site, there is a possibility that some files may have been left out. If you right click > inspect, are you getting any 404 errors?

Again, we would have to see the code (and possibly a link to the site) in order to accurately diagnose.